# Why is this x86 assembly program segfaulting?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm using the NASM x86 assembler with the ld linker, assembling to Mach-O format on MacOS.  I gave myself a challenge of writing a program that draws a box in the terminal, the challenge being that I would try to implement the exact same program with as close to the exact same behavior as possible in almost every language I know.  When I got to implementing it in x86 assembly, I ran into some problems.  I made several mistakes with using the wrong syntax, using the wrong bit-width, etc. and I managed to spot and fix most of them.  Here's the program so far:

```
global start

segment .data
width   dd      5
height  dd      5

segment .bss
chr     resb    2       ;; Current character to print

segment .text
start:
        mov     byte [chr+1],0  ;; Null-terminate chr
top     mov     byte [chr],43   ;; + character
        call    print
        call    exit

print   push    dword 1     ;; Arg 3 for write
        push    dword chr   ;; Arg 2 for write
        push    dword 0     ;; Arg 1 for write
        mov     eax,4       ;; 4 = write system call
        add     esp,-4      ;; Align esp
        int     80h         ;; Software interrupt
        ret                 ;; Return to caller

exit    push    dword 0     ;; Arg 1 for exit
        mov     eax,1       ;; 1 = exit system call
        add     esp,-4      ;; Align esp
        int     80h         ;; Software interrupt
        ret                 ;; Return to caller
```

I noticed I was getting a segfault after the program prints the `+` character to the terminal.  It appears to be doing this during the execution of the `print` subroutine, rather than when it exits.  Originally the `chr` string was only one byte wide, but I added another byte when I realized it would need to be null-terminated.  That still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You unbalanced the stack.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: `ret` is just a `pop eip`; it only works if ESP is pointing to the return address pushed by `call`.

Comment: So does that mean I should `add esp,16` before doing `ret`?

Comment: Ah yes, that actually worked.